# Array list algorithm - Interview

Tags: java, algorithm, collections

I was asked this question in an interview today. I have tried a solution but would like to know if there's a better way to solve this:

**Question**: I have an arraylist say of 500,000 elements such that the value of each element of the arraylist is same as the index. For ex: list.get(0) = 0; list.get(1) = 1 ...etc. But only one element is out of sync with this ordering [i.e list.get(i) != i]. How do you find that element.

**My Answer**: Iterate over the list using multiple threads each thread handling a certain splice of the arraylist each time comparing list.get(i) with i. When the element is found, set some boolean variable to indicate to other threads that the element has been found.

Is there a way to solve this problem without iterating over the list? Or a better way?

Comment: With no hints about where this number might be in the list, the question is kind of boring.

Comment: I think you have to explain what "only one element is out of sync" really means.. it doesn't make sense.. see my answer below. I think if you move one element all the remaining elements will be out of sync, no?

Comment: @dued0r the element is not being removed. The interviewer asked how to identify the element whose value is not the same as the index.

Comment: I think it's not about to find a way to access simultaneously different areas ... it's more about reducing the data access ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the worst case you have to examine each element, so you can't improve on the `O(n)` time complexity.

With this in mind, the best algorithm is to scan the array list from start to finish. This way you're making best use of the available memory bandwidth.

It is not entirely clear to me how or why threading has entered the picture. It seems out of place. Was it part of the question?

Comment: The question is quite dull this way, although I agree with your opinion.

Comment: @aix No, That was my answer to the interviewer. I was thinking that using an array splice and handling the iteration of the arraylist would actually be better but i realized later that O(n) cannot be improved even with multiple threads. In fact threads will only introduce more complexity.

Comment: Though you can come at the problem from both ends of the list in the same loop.

Comment: @NickHolt: Well, there's any number of ways in which one could try to partially unroll that loop. It would require profiling to be able to say anything meaningful about performance implications though (and of course it won't change the `O(n)`).

Comment: Yup, adding threads won't help if the memory I/O is the bottleneck. Most CPUs have one interface to external memory so more threads on multiple cores won't help.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is: one iteration. Your mention of concurrency of cause is something they are fishing for.

In fact since java 8, the solution whether parallel or not is simple. I think the most would have brought:

```
OptionalInt foundInt = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
    .parallelStream()
    .filter(i -> i != list.get(i))
    .findAny();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do better than `O(n)`.

And secondly, I think it's a bad idea to talk about threads and multithreading in those problems. They are not of interest at all. In the end you have a runtime of O(whatever) where your constant is removed anyway.

Maybe the interviewer meant a sorted array with elements from 0 to n-1 with index 0 to n-1. And then move one element to a different position. But that means that all the remaining elements have different indexes! In this scenario you can improve your search with binary search:

Then you can get the element in `O(log n)`. Start in the middle and check whether the index equals the element. If it is equal do the same with the upper part of the half, if not use the other part.

Comment: I agree. And 500 000 isn't even much for a single thread to iterate through nowadays

Comment: Your `O(log n)` algorithm seems to fail on the list `1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5`.  Instead of move, did you mean remove?  Then it works.

Comment: @btilly I think what he means is that if the general rule is f(n+1)=f(n)+1 (except that particular target), then a binary search is ideal here.

Comment: @btilly: why does it fail on this list? I'll find the element 0 in O(log n).. in this case every element has a different index.. so we look for index 0...

Comment: @duedl0r I moved element 1 to element 0, but the indexes of everything else was not touched.  Therefore when you look at the midpoint, you'll see that it has not changed and look in the upper half.

Comment: @JingtengXue I agree that your version of the rule works.  However I was nitpicking that "move one element to a different position" does not result in a list meeting that description.

Answer (score 0):

Further to @aix's answer, how about doing 2 checks per loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size / 2; i++)
{
  if (i != list.get(i))
  {
    return i;
  }
  else if (list.size - i != list.get(list.size - i)
  {
    return list.size - i;
  }
}
```

Comment: My view is that, in the absence of performance benchmarks loop unrolling is best left to the JIT compiler.

Comment: @aix yeah, I'd agree, purely in terms of readability I'd avoid doing something like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. iterate through the list 
2. check for the condition in the elements
3. when that only element found break out the loop...
```

I Don't think Thread Enters the Arena...

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Integer> s = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i=0; i<500000; i++) {
    s.add(i);
}

s.set(13, 500002);

for (int j=0; j<s.size(); j++) {
    if (j != s.get(j)) {
        System.out.println(j + " " + s.get(j));
    }   
}
```